# How to correctly create an ActiveRecord of an NxN table?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following database in my Rails application

```
def change
    create_table :animals do |t|
      t.string :name

      t.timestamps
    end

    create_table :owners do |t|
      t.string :name

      t.timestamps
    end

    create_join_table :animals, :owners do |t|
        t.string :description

        t.timestamps
    end
end
```

How can I create an ActiveRecord of the `animals_owners` table, like: `AnimalOwner`,
that when I execute `AnimalOwner.create(...)` it uses the `animals_owners` table, and not `animal_owners`?

Comment: Are you asking how to make the `animals_owners` table get the name `animal_owners` instead? If so, why? What's the problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: Hello. I would like to know how to make an ActiveRecord that points to the table `animals_owners` :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2 ways I am aware of to achieve what you want:

1. You can specify the join table name when creating the table as `animal_owners` by adding `table_name` option (read about other options [here](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements/create_join_table)) then create `AnimalOwner` model normally. I prefer this way
2. You can create the join table with name as `animals_owners` (the default name) then create `AnimalOwner` model and add `self.table_name = animals_owner` inside the model (`self.set_table_name = animals_owner` for Rails <= 3.1) to specify the table name that does not follow Rail conventions

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply, @Thang. I will wait a bit more to see if there are more ways to do this. Cheers :) (btw: I loved the second way to do that, if there are no other ways)

Comment: 3. Just follow the conventions and name the table `animal_owners` and spend your time on something that really matters.